# network operation of texmaker

Tags: texmaker

Is it possible to open texmaker with a specified texmaker.ini file unique to
the (linux) user? We serve texmaker from a central file server, and the only way that I have found to allow users to save their individual settings is to save a texmaker.ini file, then upon opening texmaker, reload the saved texmaker.ini file.